# What is the close form of the sum of reciprocals of $k!$, $k!!$, and so on? Moreover, is it transcendental?

Tags: special-functions, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

For $k \geq 3$, let

$$g(k) := \frac{1}{k!} + \frac{1}{k!!} + \frac{1}{k!!!} + \dots.$$ where $$k!!=(k!)!, \quad k!!!=(k!!)!$$ and so on

What is the closed form of $g(k)$? Is it a transcendental number or irrational number or both for all $k\geq3$?

Comment: Pretty much answered in the comments at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/250215/what-is-the-close-form-of-the-sum-of-reciprocals-of-k-k-and-so-on-more

Comment: If you are summing the reciprocal multifactorials, there is a closed form  in terms of the incomplete Gamma function, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReciprocalMultifactorialConstant.html

Comment: @gammatester: I don't understand the definitions in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Multifactorials : With e.g. $k:=n$ there one gets $n!^{(n)}=n$ and on the other hand (*alternative extension*) one gets $n!^{(n)}=\frac{n^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{n}+1)}$. These definitions are not compatible.

Comment: @user90369: what gammatester wrote in hint is I think indicates a different definition of multifactorial than what I'm looking for. According to my definition$$k!!=(k!)$$$$k!!!=(k!!)!$$ and so on.

Comment: Yes, obviously there are different definions. Therefore it would be good if you explain in your post what the meaning of the symbols are (not as a comment because not everybody will read it).

Comment: thanx for suggestion

Comment: I won't expect there to exist a simple closed form however finding a good approximation for this series is extemely easy: just throw everything apart from the first two terms. This will be accurate to over $10^{10^{23}}$ decimal digits for all $k > 3$. For $k>7$ keeping only the first term will be accurate to over $100.000$ decimal digits.

Answer (score 4):

I'll post the answer I put in the comments on the MathOverflow post, since I have no idea if that will vanish.

You can show that is $g(k)$ always transcendental by using the [Liouville criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number) (we'll use a version that guarantees irrationality as well).

**Liouville Criterion:** Fix $\alpha$ a real number.  If for all positive integers $n$ there are infinitely many $(p,q)$ such that $$0 < \left|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}\right| < \frac{1}{q^n},$$ then $\alpha$ is irrational and transcendental.

Now to apply this, let $\alpha$ be the sum of your series.  If $p/q$ is the $m^{\text{th}}$ partial sum of your series, the denominator $q$ is $k!!\cdots m \cdots !$.  The remainder is a negligible constant times $k!!\cdots m+1 \cdots !$, which we'll denote $r$.  (Sorry for the nonstandard repeated-factorial notation; I was too lazy to set something better up.)

It will be enough to show that $\log r > n \log q$; Stirling's approximation gives that $\log r \approx q \log q$.  So provided that $m$ is big enough that $k!!\cdots m \cdots ! > n$ (not hard to achieve!) we're done.

Comment: I'm curious as to what a rational transcendental number would look like...? I'd always thought that rational numbers were algebraic.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier I think dvitek is just referring to the OP's use of "transcendental, irrational or both?".  OP appears to be unaware that all transcendentals are irrational.

Comment: Right, I didn't notice at first glance.